# In the FL studio for doing a chicken pickin' how can I add a mute note to the piano roll?

Tags: guitar, piano, strings, fl-studio

In [this video](https://youtu.be/KrfUTgD6I7c?t=421), he says he mutes a string; for creating a sound like that in a piano roll in the FL studio, what should I do?

I was using Ploc2, and I changed multiple settings, but I couldn't make a sound like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "mute note" in MIDI- or in the FL studio piano roll.  You can't make that sound in the FL studio piano roll (technically, you can't make any sound in the FL studio piano roll, because the piano roll is just instructions for the instrument which will actually make the sound).

You are using the Ploc 2 preset for Harmor, which I don't believe can create this sound out of the box.  You could create (or find) a different synth patch that makes that sound, using this patch only for "muted" notes, or modify the existing one so that modulating some parameter (mod X, mod Y, velocity, etc) creates that sound.

I'm not totally sure what sound you're envisioning, since the Ploc 2 regular sound isn't super similar to a guitar's regular sound to begin with, but perhaps just try playing a high G with Mod X 0%, Mod Y 50%, Mod Z 100%.  Maybe you could also edit Mod X to shorten the low pass filter envelope more aggressively, further "muting" the note.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t use FL but I have had a bit of success simulating muted guitar sounds with a different DAW by making the notes I want to sound muted be as short as you can make them, a 1/64 or even a 1/128 or shorter if possible. Another thing you can do is select a specific pitch and use only that pitch for all the muted notes. Experiment with notes in different registers to see which best simulates a muted string when played with a very short duration. Also experiment with the velocity of the muted notes, they may need to be louder than the regular notes to sound good.

Below is an image with long and short 8th notes on a C note to give you an idea of what you can try:

[image]